# Mutation Observer to observe parent DOM Element whose childs are changing

Tags: javascript, mutation-observers

I am working on fetching some data from a website whose data is in a mutation state. I want to observe every change that appears on a table row. I have attached my mutation observer with the table body whose rows are changing. As every change appears on a table column therefore my code only gives me the column that is changing whereas I need a table row whose column is changing. I am unable to fetch that mutated row. Please tell me what change makes me read a mutated row from a table body.

```
$( window ).ready(function() {

    // Select the node that will be observed for mutations
    let tableBody = document.getElementById('wtbl8bb9e9b5-1b29-4f8d-909f-2837b994bfc7').children[1];

    // Options for the observer (which mutations to observe)

    let options = {
        childList: true,
        attributes: false,
        characterData: false,
        subtree: true,
        attributeOldValue: false,
        characterDataOldValue: false
    };


    //Callback function to execute when mutations are observed
    let callback = function(mutationsList, observer) {

    for(const mutation of mutationsList) {
        console.log("MutationRecord: "+MutationRecord);
        if (mutation.type === 'childList') {
                    console.log(mutation.target);
                    console.log(mutation)
                    console.log('A child node has been added or removed.');
                    console.log(mutation.addedNodes);
                    mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function(added_node) {
                        //if(added_node.id == 'child') {
                            console.log('#child has been added');
                            console.log(added_node);
                        });
        }
        else if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
            console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
        }
    }
};

// Create an observer instance linked to the callback function
let observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

// Start observing the target node for configured mutations
observer.observe(tableBody, options);

});
```

Comment: Use `added_node.closest('tr')`

Comment: It is working with this code `mutation.target.closest('tr')`. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

the `mutation` partent is `.target`, the `.target` parent is `.parentNode`.

```js
mutation.target.parentNode;
```